# How to call some function at file download request in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am something new to python.Is there exist some library in bottle or some other framwork or in python by which i can handle file download i.e. i want to develope code by which i can authorize person by some key he need to specify me key in url then only he can download file otherwise he cannot download that file.

**In simple i want to call some event that called when file download request is made.On file download request i need to perform some function After that file download start.**

Comment: Can you please make the question a bit more clear? Like "What user does, step-by-step is: 1... 2... etc." "The result of each step is: " etc.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. I think the answer is "Yes, any framework can be made to do that" Pick a framework, work through the quickstart/tutorial and ask a question about that specific framework if you haven't worked it out by then

Comment: In simple i want to call some event that called when file download request is made.On file download request i need to perform some function After that file download start.

Comment: My first priority is bottle framwork.

Comment: @HitulMistry maybe this will help you. http://blog.zacharyvoase.com/2009/09/08/sendfile/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to understand, but if I understand correctly what you want to do, your best bet probably isn't to look for this functionality inside your Python framework.  The reason for this is that most frameworks--at the very least `django` and `flask`, which I've used--aren't built to be production-ready servers, and are meant primarily to serve dynamic web page templates and URL routing, as well as other server-side functionality.  Delivery of static files and media is usually best done by a production server like Apache, `gunicorn`, or something else.

That is why, in the `django` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/) for example, it specifically says:

> Django itself doesn’t serve static (media) files, such as images,
>   style sheets, or video. It leaves that job to whichever Web server you
>   choose.
>
> The reasoning here is that standard Web servers, such as Apache,
>   lighttpd and Cherokee, are much more fine-tuned at serving static
>   files than a Web application framework.

This piece of authentication is probably better dealt with by your server, be it Apache or something else.

One option that you have for using your framework to protect downloading a file is by hiding the true file URL behind another one that requires authentication, possibly changing the real URL to the file.  This isn't perfect and definitely does not fully secure the file, but might work for you.  An example with `django`:

```py
# urls.py
...
url('/my/file/url', my_file_download_function),
...

# views.py
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_file_download_function(request):
    if request.GET.get('apikey', None) == CORRECT_API_KEY:
        return redirect('/real/URL/to/file')
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=401)
```

Again, I don't necessarily recommend this, but this is one option for doing it with a framework.

**UPDATE:**
Having read through the newly posted comments, I think your best bet was posted by **iMom0**, with the [link](http://blog.zacharyvoase.com/2009/09/08/sendfile/) about authenticating before serving static files in Django.